# How do I use the python urllib library to open web pages with a variable included in the url address?

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

Here is my code:

## enter year and file type you are looking for

```
year = input('What year is the master index you are looking for?\n')
file = input('What form are you looking for?\n')
import urllib.request
index_url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/QTR2/master.idx'%(year))
```

Will this open the web page corresponding to the year I specify as the variable?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the file and manipulate it in your script you'd probably want to do something such as this...

```
import requests
year = input('What year is the master index you are looking for?\n')
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/QTR2/master.idx' % year
resp = requests.get(url)
print(resp.text)
```

This will fetch the constructed URL and print the content of whatever is returned. I used requested here rather than urllib, it's what most people like to use these days as it's very simple and easy to use, it's also Python 2 and 3 capable, you can install it via PyPi, e.g. `pip install requests`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  I have one more question.  Is there a way to use string formatting to add both variables year and form in the url variable?  i.e. a user enters the year and form required and both get inserted into the url at a predefined place?

Comment: Yes, you can totes do that, something like this should work... ```my_url = 'http://blabla.com/bla/%s/hello/page/%s/' % (year, form)``` The variables within the parenthesis get inserted into the URL in the order they appear for each corresponding %s.